# AWS Amplify: NodeJS and MSSQL cannot connect to database

Tags: node.js, sql-server, amazon-web-services, express

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const awsServerlessExpressMiddleware = require('aws-serverless-express/middleware')
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(awsServerlessExpressMiddleware.eventContext())  

// Enable CORS for all methods
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
  next()
});

// Connect to DB
const sql = require("mssql")

const config = {
    server: "SERVER",
    user: "USER",
    password: "PASSWORD",
    port: 1433,
    database: "DATABASE"
}

console.log("Attemping to connect...")
let q = "SELECT * FROM QUERY"
// Async Await
async function getDB() {
    console.log("Inside getDB...")
    try {
        let pool = await sql.connect(config)
        console.log("Connected")
        let item = await pool.request().query(q)
        console.log(item)
        sql.close()
        return item;
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("Query did not complete.")
        console.log(err.message);
        sql.close();
    }
}
let result = getDB();
console.log("Result: " + result)
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

  res.status(200).json({result, url:req.url})

});
```

I am running an application using AWS amplify and I am trying to connect to an RDS database through my backend lambda function. When I check CloudWatch I get a failed connection to database. I'm not certain what the issue is because I use the exact same settings to connect using Python using the pyodbc library.

[CloudWatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRBNT.png)

Comment: Is your RDS instance public?

Comment: If you kept your RDS & lambda private(inside a VPC) then you should have an ingress rule defined for port 1433 in the RDS security group to allow traffic from the lambda security group.

Comment: My RDS instance is not public. It is inside a VPC with a NAT gateway. I setup the lambda security group and VPC correctly for port 1433.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mysql = require('mysql')
var connection = mysql.createPool({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "snappay",
  port : "3306"
})
connection.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if (err) {
        if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
            console.error('Database connection was closed.')
        }
        if (err.code === 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR') {
            console.error('Database has too many connections.')
        }
        if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
            console.error('Database connection was refused.')
        }
    }
    if (connection) connection.release()
    return
})
module.exports = connection
```

please follow this connection code hope it'll work
ref : https://github.com/vishalims095/nodeJS_Mysql/blob/developer/src/Modules/connection.js

Comment: This is for mysql and not microsoft sql server. They are two different databases.